# Having problems pickling and loading for class

Tags: python, class, dictionary, object, pickle

So the prompt is:
Phase 1: Employee Class

Write a class named Employee that holds the following data about an employee in attributes: name, ID Number, department, and job title.

Once you have written the class, write a program that creates three Employees objects to hold the following data:

Name, ID Number, Department, Job Title

Susan Meyers 47899 Accounting Vice President

Mark Jones 39119 IT Programmer

Joy Rodgers 81774 Manufacturing Engineer

The program should store this data in the three objects, then display the data for each employee on the screen.

Phase 2: Employee Management System

This exercise assumes you have created the Employee class for Phase 1.  Create a program that stores Employee objects in a dictionary.  Use the employee ID number as the key.  The program should present a menu that lets the user perform the following actions:

- Look up an employee in the dictionary
- Add a new employee to the dictionary
- Change an existing employee's name, department, and job title in the dictionary
- Delete an employee from the dictionary
- Quit the program

When the program ends, it should pickle the dictionary and save it to the file.  Each time the program starts, it should try to load the pickled dictionary from the file.  If the file does not exist, the program should start with an empty dictionary.

SO for the most part I was able to create the class, and I was able to create the menu, I'm having problems with putting the employees in the file and loading so that I can use the menu. Here's my code:

```
import EmployeeClass
import pickle



def lookup(dictionary):
    id_num = input("What is the employee's ID number")
    if id_num in dictionary.keys():
    print(id_num, ":", dictionary[id_num].str())
else:
    print("I'm sorry we don't have that number in our registry. Try again")
    lookup(dictionary)

def add(dictionary):
    name = input("What is their name?")
    id_num = input("What is their ID number?")
    department = input("What department do they work in?")
    title = input("What position do they hold?")
    entry = EmployeeClass.Employee(name, id_num, department, title)
    dictionary[id_num] = entry
    return dictionary

def change(dictionary):
    id_num = input("Enter the ID Number off the employee you would like to change:")
    if id_num in dictionary.keys():
        tempID = id_num
        newName = input("What would you like to change the name to?")
        newID = input("What would you like to change their ID Number to?")
        newDepartment = input("What department does this person work in?")
        newTitle = input("What title does this person hold?")
        entry = EmployeeClass.Employee(newName, newID, newDepartment, newTitle)
        dictionary[newID] = entry
        del dictionary[tempID]
        print("Employee changed successfully")
    else:
        print("Employee not found. Try again")


    def delete(dictionary):
        id_num = input("Enter the ID Number of the employee that would like to delete")
        if id_num in dictionary.keys():
        del dictionary[id_num]
    else:
        print("That employee was not found")


def save_close(dictionary):
    output_file = open('employee.dat', 'wb')
    pickle.dump(dictionary, output_file)
    output_file.close()


def main():
    employee_data = open("employee.dat", 'wb')
    emp1 = EmployeeClass.Employee("Susan Myers", 47899, "Accounting", "Vice President")
    emp2 = EmployeeClass.Employee("Mark Jones", 39119, "IT", "Programmer")
    emp3 = EmployeeClass.Employee("Joy Rodgers", 81774, "Manufacturing", "Engineer")
    pickle.dump(emp1, employee_data)
    pickle.dump(emp2, employee_data)
    pickle.dump(emp3, employee_data)
    employee_data.close()
    input_file = open('employee.dat', 'rb')
    pickle.load(input_file)
    input_file.close()
    employee_dictionary = {}

     next = True
     while next:
        print("Welcome to the the Employee Management System. Would you like to:\n")
        print("Lookup an employee? Press 1 \n")
        print("Add a new employee? Press 2 \n")
        print("Alter an existing employee? Press 3 \n")
        print("Delete an existing employee's information? Press 4 \n")
        print("Save and Close? Press 5 \n")

        user_choice = input(int())
        menu = {"1": lookup, "2": add, "3": change, "4": delete, "5": save_close}
        x = menu[user_choice](employee_dictionary)

        if user_choice == 2:
            employee_dictionary.update(x)
        if user_choice ==3:
            employee_dictionary.update(x)
        if user_choice ==4:
            employee_dictionary.update(x)

main()
```

So luckily I was able to figure out the pickling problem thanks to someone who answered, but after that when loading the menu it says that my Employee object has not attribute keys. Thank you for your responses!

Comment: please try to isolate exactly what your question is, with as minimal overhead as necessary and edit your post (people will be much more likely to respond).   Currently there is too much context to wade through

Comment: Sorry this is my first posting, I should have thought about that a little more.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is you're not assigning the depickled file to any variable.

You need to change this block of code

```
    input_file = open('employee.dat', 'rb')
    pickle.load(input_file)
    input_file.close()
    employee_dictionary = {}
```

to

```
    input_file = open('employee.dat', 'rb')
    employee_dictionary=pickle.load(input_file)
    input_file.close()
```

Only then would you be able to access the pickled dictionary.

Comment: OH wow, I feel dumb. So I was able to do that, but when I ran it after it gave me an error saying Employee object has no attribute keys. What would you recommend?

Comment: Just make sure, that employee is a dict for sure try printing a type() statement for it and check it out. Also you could upvote the answer is it helped you.